# Strange deadlock in C# with single thread and no recursion

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, deadlock

I am running into a strange behavior of my C# application.

I am running the application in debug mode via VS2010 and after several hours the application just waits for a lock release but the only thread which is alive is the one that waits upon the lock to be released and there is not recursion in that function:

```
class ProductionNode        {  
   private readonly object _lock = new object();  
   public bool Activate( long jobId )  
   {  
       lock(_lock) // Doesn't go through here  
       {  
         return DAL.InsertJobIfNotExists(jobId)>0; //SQL PLAIN INSERT IF NOT EXIST COMMAND  
       }  
  }
  public void HasJobs()  
  {  
       lock(_lock)
       {
           return DAL.HasProductionJobs();
       }  
  }
 }
```

Again, when I am pausing the application using the VS2010 the only thread that uses the ProductionNode is the one that waits for the _lock object to be released.

To make things clear, the application might activate the production node in several threads **but the in the given scenario where the deadlock occur the VS only displays a single thread which uses the ProductionNode object, the other threads uses other object types.**

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Doron

Comment: wild guess but maybe to lock an object it can't be `readonly`?

Comment: This is the only point in code where that lock gets ever taken? This part of the code looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @Dan locking doesn't happen on the reference itself but on the instance. So `readonly` should have no effect.

Comment: It does not matter that the lock field is readonly.

Comment: Why do you have a lock if you're not doing multithreading? Sounds fishy...

Comment: The problem can obviously not be just in the code you provided. Please try to provide a minimal sample that reproduces the problem

Comment: I have just added clarifications.

Comment: revise your edit (`void` method is returning something)

Comment: You have to be misunderstanding something from your debugging. It's not possible for a single thread to wait for a lock it holds itself - recursion or not; If it already holds the lock itself, it is permitted to enter subsequent protected blocks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using `windbg` (Dbugging Tools for Windows, included in the Windows SDK) and [psscor2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5c068e9f-ebfe-48a5-8b2f-0ad6ab454ad4&displaylang=en) to debug into your problem  a little deeper.

Basically, in `windbg` try to:

1 . Load psscor2:

> .load C:\tools\psscor2\amd64\psscor2 *[replace with the path where you put the psscor2 dll]*

2 . Try finding which threads are holding what locks using

`!syncblk`

3 . Look at what threads are running and compare to the threads that are holding locks

`!threads`

4 . Switch between threads

`~Xs *[where X is the thread id you got from !threads and that you are interested in because it's holding a lock]*`

1. look at the managed call stack of the current thread to find out what happened before the lock was acquired

`!clrstack -a`

**EDIT:**

Since you're presumably using .net 4, you might want to use [SOSEX](http://www.stevestechspot.com/default.aspx) instead of psscor2. I haven't really used SOSEX so far, but I'd have a look at the deadlock command: `!dlk`

Answer (score 1):

Some hints that may help. I would go these steps:

1. Right click on `_lock` and find all
   references using Visual Studio
   context menu. Maybe you are using
   the lock somewhere else (you did in your update).
2. Make sure the lock is not `static`
   and `ProductionNode` class is not
   `singleton`
3. It is possible your thread is
   trapped inside
   `DAL.InsertJobIfNotExists` so
   logging it's entrance and exit
   would help tracing the problem root.